# The import org.apache.axis2.AxisFault cannot be resolved. What dependency installs necessary AxisFault?

Tags: java, spring

Tried adding a dependency for a recently installed project. Uses

```
import org.apache.axis2.AxisFault;
```

Dependency is:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis2.wso2/axis2 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis2.wso2</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1-wso2v54</version>
</dependency>
```

Error message is

Missing artifact org.apache.axis2.wso2:axis2:jar:1.6.1-wso2v54

In any case I can't find out where this import comes from. Googled it and none of those dependencies worked. Tried:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis2/axis2 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.9</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis/axis -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Still nothing.

pom file is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<!-- 
<parent>
    <groupId>org.orgname.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>ORGNAME-Parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</parent>
 -->
<name>PDM-ProjectName</name>
<groupId>org.orgname.apps.pdm</groupId>
<artifactId>ProjectName</artifactId>
<version>2.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<description>static web-based 'reports' to provide a view of Windchill data</description>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <junit.version>4.8.2</junit.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.6.1</slf4j.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis2/axis2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.9</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis/axis -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
            
                        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis2.wso2/axis2 -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.axis2.wso2</groupId>
<artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
<version>1.6.1-wso2v54</version>
</dependency>
                        
                


                        
        
        
        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.orgname.utils</groupId>
        <artifactId>ess-proxies</artifactId>
        <version>3.5-RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

I really think this is just a problem with the dependency, as a simple import isn't working right, and I'm having trouble finding the right dependency to work that has the right file AxisFault in its packages. For some reason though axis2 doesn't contain the right things I need. If someone grabs the same dependencies I do, do they see

```
import org.apache.axis2.AxisFault;
```

working correctly, not giving an error message? I'm a bit lost, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

Answer was here:
https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.apache.axis2/axis2-kernel/1.7.7/source-code/org/apache/axis2/AxisFault.java

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis2-kernel</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.7</version>
</dependency>
```